# How to I extract text from the last group of a regex when index is not known?

Tags: regex

I have the following sample text:

Do Drink coffee

Do Write a lot of code

Do Success

They are three distinct strings that contain one or more than one word.

I want to write one regular expression such that it returns the last word in the string in all cases. The content in the string itself will be completely different in each case.

For the first string "Do Drink coffee", the output I expect is "coffee".
For the second string "Do Write a lot of code", the output I expect is "code".
For the first string "Do Success", the output I expect is "Success".

So far I have

```
string = "Do Drink Coffee";    
extractText = string.match(/Do (\S+)/)[2];
```

I get Coffee in this case, but in the second case I will get "a" instead of "code" and the third case will error out.

Thanks!

Comment: You may use `/\bDo\s.*\b(\S+)$/` as regex

Comment: What are the criteria? Do you just need to match the last word? If that's the case a simple `\S+$` does the trick.

Comment: `I get Coffee in this case, but in the second case I will get "a" instead of "code"` neither case seems true. For that reason, your question is unclear and should be clarified. As it is now it should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex with a greedy `.*` in the middle to be able to match last 1+ non-whitespace characters.

```
/\bDo\s.*\b(\S+)$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VJeHN0/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `Do`: Match `Do`
- `\s`: Match a whitespace
- `.*`: Match 0 or more characters (greedy)
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(\S+)`: Match 1+ non-whitespace character and match in group #1
- `$`: End

Answer (score 0):

Your question sort of ... "leaves out" an explanation for what, exactly, you want the expression to match.  Do you need just a Regular-Expression that returns the last word in a Sentence?  Do you need a Regular-Expression that returns the last word in any sentence that begins with the word "Do"?  What I think would help a lot would be **"Counter Examples"** that should not match the expression you are looking to write.

I can provide my guess / interpretation here... by looking at the **`String's`** you have cited above (in the question):

> `^Do\b.*?\b(\w+)$`

The above Regular Expression, when applied to the text / sentences that was posted would return the following results for **`match-group-1`***

> - coffee
> - code
> - Success

Just to ***summarize*** the expression I post, it will match any sentence whose first character after the previous `\n` (newline) in the text starts with the English-Word **'Do'**, and that the **D** in **'Do'** is capitalized.  It also specifies that the text must fit on a single line since the **`'.'`** character doesn't match a newline.

The only capture group is **`"Capture Group 1"`**, and it may contain a single word without any spaces or punctuation.  This is identified by the **`"(\w+)"`** part of the expression.  The parenthesis signify that this part of the expression is a capture group.

The opening **`'^'`** and closing **`'$'`** are used to signify / represent the beginning and ending of the line of text (as long as your are not in `"Multi-Line Mode."`)

Comment: I need just a Regular-Expression that returns the last word in a Sentence (group of words)

Comment: `\b(\w+)$`   This returns the last word before a line-break.  `\b(\w+)\n` would also work.  (as long as you know how to retrieve **Capture Group 1** - which is what the parenthesis are for)